# php code not working from php str_replace function inside

Tags: php, str-replace

i want run php code inside str_replace();

examples:

data example is here:

```
"file":"https://example.com/hls2/02/00008/,kioaker9jwxw_n,.urlset/master.m3u8%22,%22id%22:%22kioaker9jwxw"}
```

My php code example:

```
$replace1 = str_replace('"file":"', '"file":"https://otherdomain.com/palx/test/?v=\<?php echo base64_encode("', $data);

$replace2 = str_replace('m3u8', 'm3u8")?\>', $replace1);
```

Edit;::::

i want change "example.com/m3u8" to other.com/ex.php?v=example.com/m3u8 but base64 encoded from data.

data contains one more links.

And contains tokens so changing file to file.

i can't touch /hls2/02/.... because changing file to file, this is auto bot.

Comment: You are already in PHP. Don't use `<?php` again. `$replace1 = str_replace('"file":"', '"file":"https://otherdomain.com/palx/test/?v=' . base64_encode($link), $data);
` or something like that, not really clear where/what the `link` is

Comment: Sorry, question is very unclear. Can you please explain in words what you have and what you require? The 2 different code snippets and different results make it hard to follow. Maybe `v` parameter is a base64encoded value you want to decode and replace somewhere?